# BootStrap Horizontal row along with label and dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[Example of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILWa4.png)

My design page should contain label, dropdownlist and autosearch text box and a button control.
I am trying to put the whole thing in Horizantal row but its not working fine plz help..

Comment: Post your HTML Code

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show your code/efforts; like what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what is going on without some sample code or more information on what you have already tried, what you are expecting and where it is all going wrong but in general if you want to have multiple elements in one single row, you will need to put them inside of divs with a col style. the correct col style will depend on how much of the available space the col should occupy. In bootstrap your rows are divided by 12 columns, so if you want one element in the row, the column div should contain the style of col-md-12. The basic naming convention of the column class is as follows; a pre-fix of col followed by a hyphen, then the size of the display which the style should apply to (md for medium, sm for small, xs for extra small), followed by another hyphen completed with the total columns in which the div will occupy. This is very well explained in bootstraps official documentation so maybe head on over there and do some quick reading first (e.g. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Example Label</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i am trying

```
        <form class ="form-inline" role="form">
             <div class ="form-group">
                <label for="Device">Device Manager</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>

            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">AutoSearch</label>
            <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Auto Search"/>
                 </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-btn-primary">Search</button>

        </form>
```

Comment: This snipped should probably be added into the question instead of an answer.